# TypeError: (0 , _services_cryptoApi__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.useGetCryptosQuery) is not a function

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

I am using redux toolkit for the first time and I can't figure out what the problem is.
The error code is: Uncaught TypeError: (0 , *services_cryptoApi__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2*_.useGetCryptosQuery) is not a function

I have react version 18.2.0 and redux toolkit version 1.8.6

code from API:

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';


const cryptoApiHeaders = {
  'X-RapidAPI-Key': 'key',
  'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'host'
}

const baseUrl =  'https://coinranking1.p.rapidapi.com';

const createRequest = (url) => ({ url, headers: cryptoApiHeaders});

export const cryptoApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'cryptoApi',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    gerCryptos: builder.query({
      query: () => createRequest('/coins')
    })
  })
});

export const {
  useGetCryptosQuery,
} = cryptoApi;
```

component that uses the data:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Typography, Row, Col, Statistic } from 'antd';
import { useGetCryptosQuery } from '../services/cryptoApi';

const { Title } = Typography;

const Homepage = () => {
  const { data, isFetching } = useGetCryptosQuery();
  const globalStats = data?.data?.stats;

  console.log(data)

  if(isFetching) return 'Loading...';

  return (
    <>
      <Title level={2} className="heading">Global Crypto Stats</Title>
      <Row>
        <Col span={12}><Statistic title="Total Cryptocurrencies" value={globalStats.total}/></Col>
        <Col span={12}><Statistic title="Total Exchanges" value="5"/></Col>
        <Col span={12}><Statistic title="Total Market Cap" value="5"/></Col>
        <Col span={12}><Statistic title="Total 24h Volume" value="5"/></Col>
        <Col span={12}><Statistic title="Total Markets" value="5"/></Col>
      </Row>
    </>
  )
}
```

store.js:

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

import { cryptoApi } from '../services/cryptoApi';

export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    [cryptoApi.reducerPath]: cryptoApi.reducer,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

write middleware in store.js function

```
middleware: getDefaultMiddleware =>
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat(cryptoApi.middleware)
```